# VBA Call Function not working

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call Worksheets("Chart").Range("B1").Value

End Sub
```

Error: Object doesn't support this property or method (438)

What is wrong? I have also tried using a variable i.e. x to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: `Worksheets("Chart").Range("B1").Value` returns a value if `Worksheets("Chart")` exists. A value cannot be called. But `x = Worksheets("Chart").Range("B1").Value` should work.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of that you might be trying to do is have a value in `Chart!B1` that specifies the name of a macro that the user wants to run.  If that **is** the case, you could do `Application.Run Worksheets("Chart").Range("B1").Value`.

Answer (score -2):

why are you using call? 
get the value into a variable and continue from there
dim a as variant
a = workbook. worksheet("aaa").....